# How do I evaluate an expression with variables read from cin

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a basic calculator, but I'm not getting the answer as I expect.  This is my code:

```
char x;
int y;
int z;

cout << "Welcome to the Calculator!\n";
cout << "What operation would you like to use?\n";
cin >> x;

cout << "What will be the first integer?\n";
cin >> y;

cout << "What will be the second?\n";
cin >> z;

cout << "Computing...\n";
cout << y << x << z;
```

When I execute it, if I enter `-`, `9`, and `6` for each respective prompt, I get the following output:

```
9-6
```

Likewise, if I enter `+`, `8`, and `4`, I get:

```
8+4
```

I was expecting the output to be `3` and `12`, respectively.

Comment: Are you trying to perform `9-6` and output the result (i.e. `3`)?

Comment: yup, but just having trouble

Comment: I have no idea what is the question. Please explain this more carefully.

Comment: You cannot "execute" variables in C++ - you need to write the code for it yourself (e.g.: use a `switch(x)` to check what operator was entered by the user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve this issue is just start small. Make a calculator with a single function: one that adds numbers together. Suddenly your code is:

```
cout << "What will be the first integer?\n";
cin >> y;

cout << "What will be the second?\n";
cin >> z;

auto result = y + z;
std::cout << result << "\n";
```

Nice and easy. Now think about how you'd add the ability to allow minusing. Well we need to ask which operation:

```
std::cout << "Would you like to add or subtract numbers? ";
char operation;
std::cin >> operation;

int result;
if (operation == '+')
{
    result = y + z;
}
else
{
    result = y - z;
}
```

And you can expand from there, by adding more via `if else if` or just a `switch`

```
int result;
switch (operation)
{
    case '+': result = y + z; break;
    case '-': result = y - z; break;
    case '*':
    case 'x':
        result = y * z; break;
}
```

Plus you would want to add handling for invalid operations entered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the character that the user enters and use this to determine which operation to apply. So if e.g. '-' is entered, you perform the operation `y-z`.